# Knockout binding js to template

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, ui-form

I try render input field in my custom form element like

```
<render args="ui/form/element/input"/>
```

but then i get some js errors because elem `userChanges` and others dont exist(see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html), how can i bind js component to render template, or how can i use form element inside another form element?